# Why does the is/2 predicate unifies a variable with zero?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to figure out why this piece of code actually works well.
I don't understand anything of what's going on there, how Counter1 unifies with 0, and then unifies with 1, etcetera. The Counter variable actually seems to make more sense to me, but the other one...

The following two rules define the predicate numberOfElements/2 which counts how many elements a given list has.

```
numberOfElements([], 0).
numberOfElements([_|Tail], Counter):-
    numberOfElements(Tail,Counter1),
    Counter is Counter1 + 1 .
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a `trace` on a simple example (*e.g.*, a list of 2 elements - enter `trace.` at the prompt, then `numberOfElements([a,b], N).`)? You should try it. This is a *recursive* predicate. So it will keep calling itself until it hits the base case (the first argument is finally `[]`) and instantiate the second argument as `0`. Then you get `Counter is Counter1 + 1` (with `Counter1` as `0`) which then returns to the next level of recursive call, etc. Are you familiar with recursion in general?

Comment: I'm trying to know **WHY** does the Counter1 variable unifies with a zero, I haven't tried a trace (I don't even know what that is), I already know about recursivity and most of what's going on except for what my question asks.

Comment: I explained why. It's because of the recursion down to the base case that unifies `Counter1` with `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to explain with an example.

Suppose you call `numberOfElements([a, b, c], C)`.

The only clause applicable is the second one, so discard the head of the list (`a`), unify `Tail` with `[b, c]` and the variable `C` with the variable `Counter`.

Then `numberOfElemens/2` call itself with `Tail` (unified with `[b, c]`) and a new variable, `Counter1`.

Now the only clause applicable is (again) the second one, so discard the head of the list (`b`), unify `Tail` with `[c]` and the variable `Counter1` (of the first call) with the variable `Counter` (of the second call).

Then `numberOfElemens/2` call itself, again, with `Tail` (unified with `[c]`) and a new variable `Counter1`.

Now the only clause applicable is (for the third time) the second one, so discard the head of the list (`c`), unify `Tail` with `[]` (the empty list) and the variable `Counter1` (of the second call) with the variable `Counter` (of the third call).

Then `numberOfElemens/2` call itself, again, with `Tail` (unified with empty list) and a new variable `Counter1`.

This time the only clause applicable is the first one (the list is empty) so `Counter1` of the third call is unified with zero.

Now is executed `Counter is Counter1 + 1` in the third call, `Counter1` is zero so `Counter` become 1.

But `Counter`, in the third call, is unified with `Counter1` in the second; so it's executed `Counter is Counter1 + 1` in the second call. `Counter1` is unified with 1 so `Counter` become 2.

But `Counter`, in the second call, is unified with `Counter1` in the first; so it's executed `Counter is Counter1 + 1` in the first call. `Counter1` is unified with 2 so `Counter` become 3.

Remembering that `Counter` in the first call is unified with the original `C`, so `C` is unified with 3.

I try to summarize as follows

```
counter([a, b, c], C)

--->  counter([_ | [b, c]], C = COUNTER(1))

      ---> counter([_ | [c]], COUNTER1(1) = COUNTER(2))

           ---> counter([_ | []], COUNTER1(2) = COUNTER(3))

                ---> counter([], COUNTER1(3) = 0)

           ---> COUNTER(3) is COUNTER1(3) + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1

      ---> COUNTER(2) is COUNTER1(2) + 1 = COUNTER(3) + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2

 ---> C = COUNTER(1) is COUNTER1(1) + 1 = COUNTER(2) + 1 = 2 + 1 = 3
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I understood it perfectly, this crazy backtracking, LOL.

Comment: @newbie - you're welcome; and, yes: Prolog is a little difficult at start; but fascinating.

Comment: @newbie this is unwinding of nested recursive calls, not really backtracking.

Comment: seriously? wow... actually, makes sense. you guys are really opening my mind here.